# Can Macrium clone my SSD to a bigger SSD?

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I got a 256 GB SSD. I want the partition that have 255 GB to be 1 TB

This is what I got:

[image: Partition]

It turns out the original ssd has 3 partition. I have no idea what's the use of the 2 other partition.

And the destination SSD will also have 3 partition at the same size. What I want is I want the destination SSD will have it's 1st partition to be much bigger. Is this possible?

This is how the new hard disk looks like in manage computer after this whole thing.

I wonder if I can just delete the 2 extra partitions or whether they are actually important for booting.

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Macrium Reflect, but you can rearrange partitions after cloning.

Comment: I can? How? Then move the primary all the way to the back and add the 633GB to primary?

Comment: I'd suggest moving 2nd and 3rd partitions right and then resizing 1st one. I'd suggest using GParted Live to do that. A screenshot from Windows's _Disk Management_ would be helpful to identify what these partitions do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it.

It can be done. However, first partition is small and there is a lot of unused space. I then use other stuffs, I forget, to make the windows partition bigger.

I think I used managed disk space

So the answer is yes but not in one go.